# Kendo UI: How to avoid server call when text entered in combobox is less than min length

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I am using Kendo UI ComboBox "**version:2016:1.112.545**" and using "**http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/serverfiltering**" as reference. I set the min length as three characters(search string) for the ComboBox. So when I type three characters a request to web server should be done and it is working as expected. Now the problem is when I clear the whole content in the ComboBox, again a request to web server is done(with empty search string). How to avoid this call?

(Note: This issue can be reproduced in the above telerik demos URL. Use the browser's developer tools to monitor the server calls.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Try to use below given code:-

```
filtering: function(e) {
      var filter = e.filter;

      if (!filter.value) {
        //prevent filtering if the filter does not value
        e.preventDefault();
      }
  }
```

see the in jsfildde :-
http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/1936/